# MOVXZ into register - "invalid operand for instruction"

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, kernel, att

I am trying to compile an assembler-based implementation of AES, viewable [here](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/libkern/crypto/aes/EncryptDecrypt.s). My assembler is giving me the following error, repeated several different times over what appear to be instances of the same error. The exact source location is [here](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/libkern/crypto/aes/EncryptDecrypt.s#L297), but due to the large amount of preprocessor indirection used in this file, I have copied the exact error from my build output, which gives the exact code as seen by the compiler:

```
/Volumes/Sources/Andromeda/Kernel/libkern/crypto/aes/EncryptDecrypt.s:297:19: error: invalid operand for instruction
 movzx 240(%r10), %rax
                  ^~~~
```

I do not quite understand what may be causing this problem. If I understand it properly, this instruction moves a byte (or more, this is unclear, and may in fact be the source of the problem) into the RAX register, zero-extending it if the source is less than 64-bits in size. Do I need to explicitly specify a size by adding a tag to the `movxz` instruction (e.g. `movzxb`)? What else might be the cause of this problem? Thanks!

Comment: at&t syntax does not normally use `movzx`, but maybe some assembler versions accept it. Try changing that to `movzbl 240(%r10), %eax` (assuming it was a byte source).

Comment: Or perhaps `movzbq 240(%r10), %rax`.

Comment: @FUZxxl that is overkill due to the automatic zero extension, but should work, yeah. For the record, my assembler (_GNU assembler 2.22_) does accept the original `movzx` too. OSX version might not.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I think the correct mnemonic for my situation is `movzlq` (because I am moving a 4-byte datum [`l`] into a 8-byte register [`q`]), but my assembler says that is an invalid mnemonic.

Comment: In that case just do a simple `movl 240(%r10), %eax` since 32 bit is automatically zero extended by the cpu.

Comment: @Jester That did it, all right! Could you please post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At&t syntax does not normally use `movzx`, but maybe some assembler versions accept it. My copy of GNU assembler 2.22 does, but maybe OSX version doesn't. In any case, the assembler generates code for a byte source. If you do in fact have that, the proper at&t syntax would be `movzbq 240(%r10), %rax`, or, taking advantage of automatic zero extension, `movzbl 240(%r10), %eax`.

If you have a 4 byte source, then you can't use `movzx` at all, since it does not exist for that operand type. All you need in this case is the automatic zero extension, so you can simply do `movl 240(%r10), %eax`.